# Bash Script to repeat every word in a line?

Tags: linux, bash, script, string

I have a string like: `dog cat bird whale`

And I want to get `dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale`

All the words are in the same line. Any idea?

Answer (score 28):

Adding to the family of solutions :-) .

`duplicator.sh`:

```
for i; do echo -n "$i $i "; done; echo
```

Make executable, and now:

```
$ ./duplicator.sh dog cat bird whale
dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
```

---

Alternatively as a shell function, e.g. to be reusable within a script:

```
duplicator() {
    for i; do echo -n "$i $i "; done; echo
}
```

which can then be run directly where defined as

```
duplicator dog cat bird whale
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of the shell approach.

Comment: Well I really love the simplicity of this solution

Comment: Way better than the first couple of ways I thought of.

Answer (score 21):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(\S+)/\1 \1/g' filename
```

If you want to save the changes to the file in-place, say:

```
sed -i -r 's/(\S+)/\1 \1/g' filename
```

---

You could also use `perl`:

```
perl -M5.10.0 -ne 'say join " ", map{$_, $_} split " ";' filename
```

(Add the `-i` option to save the changes to the file in-place.)

Or, as suggested by [terdon](https://superuser.com/users/151431/terdon):

```
perl -M5.10.0 -ane 'say join " ", map{$_, $_} @F;' filename
```

Quoting from [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> `@F`
>
> The array `@F` contains the fields of each line read in when autosplit
>   mode is turned on. See perlrun for the `-a` switch. This array is
>   package-specific, and must be declared or given a full package name if
>   not in package main when running under `strict 'vars'`.

Comment: Shorter: `sed -r 's/\S+/& &/g'`.

Comment: That is not a Bash script. Invoking some command (even from a Bash shell) does not consistute a Bash script.

Comment: @PeterMortensen You are technically correct (the best kind of correct), but practically every system that has bash installed will also have the standard unix tools, including sed and awk. The whole point of shell scripting (well, a large part of the point of it) is to point commands at the right place.

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is incorrect. A bash script can call external commands. A bash script should start with a shebang line, but this is not strictly necessary. The question did not specify that the bash script should not call external commands (often called a “pure bash script”).

Comment: Nice perl trick. You can make it shorter with `-a`: `perl -M5.10.0 -ane 'say join " ", map{$_, $_} @F;' `

Comment: @terdon Added your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

What would this be without an `awk/gawk` answer:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF+1;i+=1/2) { printf("%s ",$i); }}' <<<"dog cat bird whale"
dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
```

If a terminating newline is important:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF+1;i+=1/2) { printf("%s ",$i); }} END{print ""}' <<<"dog cat bird whale"
```

Comment: My firsts downvote. Just curious, why? Is there something wrong with the script? Or a more abbreviated version?

Comment: Not my downvote, but `for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s %s ",$i,$i;` is both shorter and more readable, IMHO.

Comment: Hard to argue with that, so I've simplified and shortened my answer (now takes advantage of indices being rounded down to ints) without changing the approach. Hopefully it is now clearer.

Comment: That is not a Bash script. Invoking some command (even from a Bash shell) does not consistute a Bash script.

Comment: Putting this in a script is trivial, though.

Comment: I'd be leery about using a float  as the increment. At some point you'll get 0.99999999 or 1.000000001 and you get one more/less iteration.

Answer (score 3):

```
s="dog cat bird wale"
ss=$( tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$s" | sed p | tr '\n' ' ' )
echo "$ss"
```

```
dog dog cat cat bird bird wale wale
```

Comment: I thought about writing `sed -n 'p;p'` -- I thought that was more transparent about what it's doing.

Comment: You should add that to the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you have your string in an a variable, say `foo="dog cat bird whale"`, you could do:

- Pure bash:

  ```
  $ echo "$foo" | (read a b c d && echo "$a $a $b $b $c $c $d $d")
  dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
  ```

  **Explanation:** The parentheses are needed so that the `read` and `echo` happen in the same subshell and can therefore share variables. Without them, the `echo` would just print a blank line.
- coreutils:

  ```
  $ join -j 5 -o 1.1,1.1,1.2,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.4,1.4 <(echo $foo) <(echo)
  dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
  ```

  **Explanation:** The `-o` flag of `join` allows you to set the output format. Here, I'm telling it to print the 1st field of the 1st file (`1.1`), followed by the 2nd field of the 1st file (`1.2`) etc. That way each field of the 1st file is printed twice. However, `join` is designed to, well, join *two* input lines on a common field. So, I also pass it a blank line (`<(echo)`) and then ignore it. The `-j` sets the join field, setting it to one that does not exist (the 5th) causes `join` to print the entire line.

  If you don't care about whitespace or the input order, you could do

  ```
  $ paste <(echo $foo) <(echo $foo)
  dog cat bird wale   dog cat bird wale
  ```
- Perl 1:

  ```
  $ echo $foo | perl -lane 'push @k, $_,$_ for @F; print "@k"'
  dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
  ```

  **Explanation:**

  ```
  -l: adds a newline to each print call (among other things)
  -a: turns on field splitting, fields are saved as @F
  -n: process input line by line
  -e: give a script as a command line parameter.
  ```

  The script above will save each field (from `@F`) twice in the array `@k` and then print `@k`. If you don't need the trailing newline, you could simplify to

  ```
  $ echo $foo | perl -ane 'print " $_ $_" for @F'
  ```
- Perl 2:

  ```
  $ echo $foo | perl -0040 -pne 'print "$_"' | paste - - 
  dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
  ```

  **Explanation:** The `-0` option sets the input record separator (as a hexadecimal or octal number, see [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) for conversions). Here, I am setting it to octal `040` which is a space. The `-p` makes `perl` print each input "line" and since we have set the record separator to space, lines are now defined by spaces, so every field is printed twice.
- `awk`:

  ```
  $ echo $foo | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i" "$i;} 1;}'
  dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
  ```

  **Explanation:** `NF` is the number of fields, so the script above goes through each field and appends it to itself. Once that's done, we print the line (`1;` is just shorthand for print).

Answer (score 0):

Now for a `python` answer:

From the command line:

```
$ python -c "import sys; s=sys.argv[1:]; print(' '.join(j for i in zip(s,s)for j in i));" dog cat bird whale
```

From stdin:

```
$ python -c "s=input().split(); print(' '.join(j for i in zip(s,s)for j in i));" <<<"dog cat bird whale"
```

The result in both cases:

```
dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly over-the-top, but a `haskell` answer:

```
$ ghc -e "getLine >>= putStrLn . unwords . (concatMap $ replicate 2) . words" <<<"dog cat bird whale"
dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, also using only *bash builtins*

```
$ string="dog cat bird whale"
$ twix() { while [[ ! -z $1 ]]; do printf "%s %s " $1 $1; shift; done; }
$ twix $string
dog dog cat cat bird bird whale whale
```

I don't see any benefits compared to the top answer, just to show a slightly different way, which might be better suitable for some purposes.

Comment: `echo` is also a shell builtin in Bash (test `type echo`).

Comment: @DanielAndersson : Sure, that's why I wrote "_also_ using only bash builtins", having your nice (already +1'd) answer in mind.

Comment: OK, you can classify my comment as language confusion :-) .